# How to populate a parse-server Class with a json file?

Tags: parse-server

I have a json file and I would like to use it to populate an empty Class in parse. Is there a way to do this thru the parse dashboard or do I have to do this thru the mongoDB or do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iterate thru your json, building a script file using curl and the parse rest api that does following type curl post to parse.class that you need .

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOUR_APP_ID" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
  http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/${class}
```

Comment: Can you explain it in laymen terms, im very new to parse

Comment: Also, my json isnt that big, can i just use the cli command for each instanse

Comment: check out the rest docs : https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#creating-objects  . Note that each entry from your json file corresponds to the "-d" arg above.  on the CLI you can just paste the curl expressions to add each of your class objects in a curl POST

Comment: ok the curl works but is there a way to add my own custom object id and custom createdAt and updatedAt or do i have to create my own new fields with similar names

Comment: do NOT overload those 3 fields for some tweek requirement. You should add NEW fields as required. You may index the new fields to make access more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Parse announced that has removed the import functionality support from the Parse-Dashboard so you can't do it the easy way. You can, however, use the API console in order to map out the request details for insert, delete and update actions. Once you have the details need, you can either use curl as Robert's suggested in his answer or you can do it via axios, the fetch api or what have you.

```
axios.post('<your-parse-server-url>' 
  + '/parse/classes/<your-className>', yourJsonData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'your-app-id',
    'X-Parse-Master-Key': 'your-master-key'
  }})
  .then(response => { console.log(response) })
  .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
```

For more info you may visit the [Rest API Guide](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/) already provided on Parse Dashboard.